# How can I center two floated elements within a container?

Tags: html, css, containers

This is driving me crazy.  I am relatively new to this stuff so trying to figure this one out for the past hour.  I'll be really thankful if someone can help me with this.

I have the following code:

```
<div class="middle_box">
     <div class="box left">
          Some large text
     </div>
     <div class="box right">
          Some large text as well
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.middle_box {
    height: 260px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    width: 390px;
}
```

As you can tell the width of the container is 960px.  Now, I want to center the two .box elements within the 960px container and that's where I am lost.

**What did I try?**

I tried using `margin: 0px auto;` and I tried faking it by adding margin-left on both sides but it just didn't work.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear ".middle_box", as its children elements are floated.

```
.middle_box:before, .middle_box:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.middle_box:after { clear: both; }
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

best way to use this hack calls clearfix :

```
.middle_box:after {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        height: 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using fixed widths anyway, `960px` and `390px`, why not set the margin as well?  Easy to calculate, no need for advanced CSS "magic" here in such setup.

```
.middle_box {
    height: 260px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: red;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-left: 60px; /* <--- */
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    width: 390px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  But how did you come up with the 60px?

Comment: `960px - 390px - 390px - 60px - 60px - 60px = 0px`

Comment: I am not saying my solution is the perfect or best - just the easiest, what I would do myself in that fixed scenario. Maybe a reset of padding/margin before is needed so it shows equal in all browsers, which as you know have different defaults. Only tested in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/xVc73/)

**HTML**

With floating - different dimensions

```
<div class="middle_box">
  <div class="box0 left">
      Some large text
  </div>
  <div class="box0 right">
      Some large text as well
  </div>
</div>
```

Without floating - same dimensions

```
<div class="middle_box">
  <div class="box1">
      Some large text
  </div>
  <div class="box1">
      Some large text as well
  </div>
</div>
```

With clear - one on the top of another

```
<div class="middle_box">
  <div class="box2 clear">
      Some large text
  </div>
  <div class="box2 clear">
      Some large text as well
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.middle_box {
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  width: 960px;
  height: 260px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.box0 {
  font-size: 21px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 65px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 585px;
  margin: 24px 6px 0 24px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 24px 24px 0 6px;
}
.box1 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 25px; /* margin-left | calculate 960px - boxes width - borders */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 65px;
  width: 438px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.box2 {
  font-size: 21px;
  margin: 25px auto 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  width: 442px;
  height: 65px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Centring floats is tough, but do you need to use float? Why not use:

```
display: inline-block
```

There are advantages/disadvantages to using both `float` and `inline-block` and both have their quirks but ultimately I find inline-block much more useful and easier to develop with. Here is a fiddle for the solution to your problem using `inline-block`

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/YEptp/)

Also a heads up about its white-space quirk if you do use it (but an easy one to fix):

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/