# Vertical centering of float elements (navigation controls) within a container

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, css-float, centering

I've read [How can I center two floated elements within a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776601/how-can-i-center-two-floated-elements-within-a-container) and friends; the former refers to horizontal centering, and the friends to non-floated children AFAICT. Why am I using floats? Well, read on...

Here's my desired layout:

```
+-------+-------------------+-------+
|       | ##### ##### ##### |       |
| [ < ] | ##### ##### ##### | [ > ] |
|       | ##### ##### ##### |       |
+-------+-------------------+-------+
```

The < and > are navigation arrows; # are dynamically loaded image thumbnails within a slick carousel. The images are all the same width & height, but the carousel may be configured to display more than three such images. Also, the whole thing of course needs to be responsive :)

My issue is that I am unable to vertically center the elements containing the navigation elements within the outer container. Various combinations of float: left/none, display: flex-box, overflow: auto/ hidden, margin: auto, etc etc have been tried and I am at my wit's end.

With no float, the navigation elements and carousel stack up (as expected):

```
+-------+-------------------+-------+
| [ < ]                             | 
| ##### ##### #####                 |
| ##### ##### #####                 |
| ##### ##### #####                 |
| [ > ]                             |
+-------+-------------------+-------+
```

With float: left, the nav elements refuse to center vertically - it looks like those elements don't receive the full height of the container (nav elements are divs containing a span):

```
+-------+-------------------+-------+
| [ < ] | ##### ##### ##### | [ > ] |
|       | ##### ##### ##### |       |
|       | ##### ##### ##### |       |
+-------+-------------------+-------+
```

Here's the basic (non-working) code. I've stubbed out the carousel for ease of testing. In the below code I'm using javascript just to simulate loading the (remote) images.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('img').css({
      width: '150px',
      height: '110px'
    });
  }, 1500);
});
```

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 4%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: flex-box;
  align-content: center;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 90%;
}

img {
  background: lightblue;
  display: block;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="left nav">
    <span class="left nav-arrow">&lt;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="image"> <img class="img1"> </div>
    <div class="image"> <img class="img2"> </div>
    <div class="image"> <img class="img3"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right nav">
    <span class="right nav-arrow">&gt;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not against a JS solution though would prefer a pure CSS one if possible. Also I'm not a CSS developer by day so there may be some *ahem* cargo-cult CSS rules here.

Comment: one word - flexbox - no need for floats anymore and then you can do your vertical centring too

Comment: `display: flex-box;` is incorrect. Correct would be `display: flex;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `display: flex` to your outer element as well.
I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1abu2au3/43/) and simplified the css.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('img').css({
      width: '150px',
      height: '110px'
    });
  }, 1500);
});
```

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  background: lightblue;
}

.image {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.nav-arrow {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">

  <div class="left nav">
    <span class="left nav-arrow">&lt;</span>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel">

    <div class="image"> <img class="img1"> </div>
    <div class="image"> <img class="img2"> </div>
    <div class="image"> <img class="img3"> </div>

  </div>

  <div class="right nav">
    <span class="right nav-arrow">&gt;</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

I added the snippet to my answer.

Comment: position static is default position

Comment: Thanks @Christian, this works great! One thing though, and I can open a new question if necessary, but is there a way to have the nav controls be the height of the container? I hoped height: 100% would achieve this but it does not. Full-height controls are easier to click on.

Comment: Ah, looks like that was as simple as adding "align-self: stretch" to the nav element.

Comment: Yes. Align-self is the way to go. Yhx for accepting

Answer (score 1):

Simply use **Flexbox**...for vertically center alignment use `align-items: center` and for horizontally center use `justify-content: center`

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('img').css({
      width: '150px',
      height: '110px'
    });
  }, 1500);
});
```

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  background: lightblue;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="left nav">
    <span class="left nav-arrow">&lt;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="image"> <img class="img1"> </div>
    <div class="image"> <img class="img2"> </div>
    <div class="image"> <img class="img3"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right nav">
    <span class="right nav-arrow">&gt;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```